# Where is this javascript string highlight preference?

Tags: pycharm

I've been trying to find out for a long time now where this specific syntax highlight is (I'd like to remove that background color):

[image: pycharm javascript string highlighting]

It's not in the "obvious" preference here (unless I missed something):

[image: javascript syntax highlight menu]

Where is it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deactivate it, or change how this shows, go to:

Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Code

You can change a lot of things in here, but the one you are asking for is the **Injected language fragment**. Uncheck the *background* check box on the right of this panel, Apply and then OK and you are done!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot that wasnt obvious ^^

Comment: Indeed it was not, I experimented a bit myself :)